# TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' in HTTP GET Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, get, python-requests

I am trying to execute the below python function to check the status of an invoice from an external API:

```
def getInvoice(inv_id):
    response = requests.get("https://api.example.com/invoices/"+str(inv_id)+"?access_token=123456789").json()
    return response

print(getInvoice("5b5f60384b3f"))
```

When I try to call the function, I keep receiving the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\db.py", line 82, in <module>
    print(getInvoice("5b5f60384b3f"))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\db.py", line 79, in getInvoice
    response = requests.get("https://api.example.com/invoices/"+str(inv_id)+"?access_token=123456789").json()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
[Finished in 3.0s]
```

I don't understand why this keeps happening, or where the 'set' is? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What’s the rest of the error? (The traceback with all the filenames and line numbers?)

Comment: @Ry- I've just updated the question to include the full error - thanks!

Comment: Add `raw_response = requests.get("https://api.example.com/invoices/" + str(inv_id) + "?access_token=123456789")`, `print(raw_response)`, and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your url is not returning json response. I suggest you to dubug the code by reading the response as text and check what it really contains.

```
import urllib.request

contents = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.example.com/invoices/"+str(inv_id)+"?access_token=123456789").read()

print(contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, looks like server does not reply with JSON.

Change `getInvoice` function and examine server response:

```py
def getInvoice(inv_id):
    url = "https://api.example.com/invoices/{}?access_token=123456789".format(inv_id)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()  # you will get an exception if HTTP status code != 200

    try:
        return response.json()
    except:  # for debugging purposes only
        print("Failed to obtain JSON response. Response contents:\n{}".format(response.text))
        raise
```